# Magento2 I want to change "Please specify the zip code." error message on one step checkout Canada post method

Tags: magento2, checkout, code, zip

Magento2 I want to change **"Please specify the zip code."** error message on one step checkout Canada post method

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to your theme add translation for `Magento_Shipping/i18n/en_US.CSV`
like this

> This shipping method is not available. Please specify the zip
>   code.","This shipping method is not available. Please specify the
>   Postal

Comment: Hi, I try this method and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy but the translation doesn't update. what might be the issue? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Better place your translation in the theme file app/design/frontend/<--youre theme-->/i18n/en_US.csv
Remove all items and exit the cart.

Try console comand:

- bin/magento s:up
- bin/magento c:c
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f